# I am having an error while trying to upgrade magento and instal a new theme

Tags: magento1.9.3.1

Error in file:

```
"/var/www/vhosts/mazali.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.4-1.6.2.0.5.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'customer_flowpassword' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `customer_flowpassword` (
  `flowpassword_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Flow password Id' ,
  `ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User IP' ,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Requested email for change' ,
  `requested_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Requested date for change' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`flowpassword_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_EMAIL` (`email`),
  INDEX `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_IP` (`ip`),
  INDEX `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_REQUESTED_DATE` (`requested_date`)
) COMMENT='Customer flow password' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/mazali.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mazali.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.2.0.4', '1.6.2.0.5')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mazali.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.2.0.4', '1.6.2.0.5')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mazali.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mazali.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mazali.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mazali.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mazali.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

I am  beginner can you explain slowly.

Comment: check if the table `customer_flowpassword` is empty, because the script seems to want to create a table that already exists.. if the table is empty, you can delete it and run the script again

Answer (score 1):

It would appear the script for the upgrade is trying to create a MySQL table called '`customer_flowpassword`' however this table already exists within your database.

You would have 2 options,

1. **DROP** (delete) the table from the database however you might want to back this up if the table has data in it so you can import again if desired
2. temporarily **comment out the create statement** in the sql script